# Wubi Installation completed but getting error msgs after booting for the first time

Tags: installation

I installed Ubuntu using WUBI on Windows 7 system at my office laptop.
The office laptop has a **PGP encryption application** running.

After installation, when I boot into the 12.04 installation automatically for the first boot, I get the following error message:
**Could not find the ISO /ubuntu/install/installation.iso**, on an initramfs.
I booted back Windows 7 and checked C:/ubuntu/install/installation.iso it was a 711MB iso image and I extracted the iso and found out that all the files were the files which I had on the iso image I had downloaded from the Ubuntu website. I mean basically the same folder structure and the contents were the same and I was able to extract the iso which means that the **iso file is not broken or erroneous**.

The laptop does not have a CDROM so in the initramfs, I tried mounting the pendrive which was the Ubuntu installation disk created by [Universal USB installer.exe](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button) but I was unable to mount the /dev/sda1 or /dev/sda2, I have a single hard disk partition and I assumed the pen drive would be either of the above. I didn't find an /dev/sdb parition anywhere.

Is there any way of bringing up the boot process by eliminating the error by mounting some disk which contains the same folder structure which WUBI installed on the hard drive C:/ubuntu in my case or mounting the pen drive which I converted as an installation media.

I need help on installing the Ubuntu by eliminating the errors. Please help me with the installation as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

First you should Use unetbootin software (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for making pendrive bootable for any linux system.Install with wubi for just Try out Ubuntu, but not permanent.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. My pendrive is already a bootable source. I had also booted ubuntu from it. But my wubi installation is not working when it reaches the final step of booting out ubuntu and configuring it for the first time for me. I am not allowed to partition the disk at my office that's the major problem. So only I am using wubi to install ubuntu.

Comment: Some BIOS prevent to write data on HDD. You can disable this option by going in BIOS settings. You should check Iso by comparing md5sum not, just looking at contents of folders, because sometimes due to minor problem in iso can cause problems in installation.